Compare two dataframes based on more than 1 column and deliver the change
So consider I have two dataframes:
Old information:
    Name       Id      Club     Number
0   Ronaldo    12414   Al-Nassr 7
1   Messi      4344134 Miami    30
2   Shevchenko 1234435 Milan    7
3   Maradona   37346   Retired  None

old = {'Name': {0: 'Ronaldo', 1: 'Messi', 2: 'Shevchenko', 3: 'Maradona'},
 'Id': {0: 12414, 1: 4344134, 2: 1234435, 3: 37346},
 'Club': {0: 'Al-Nassr', 1: 'Miami', 2: 'Milan', 3: 'Retired'},
 'Number': {0: 7, 1: 30, 2: 7, 3: None}}

And new information:
    Name       Id       Club        Number
0   Ronaldo    12414    Al-Nassr    7
1   Messi      4344134  Miami       10
2   Shevchenko 1234435  Retired     None
3   Neymar     423552   Al Hilal    10

new = {'Name': {0: 'Ronaldo', 1: 'Messi', 2: 'Shevchenko', 3: 'Neymar'},
 'Id': {0: 12414, 1: 4344134, 2: 1234435, 3: 423552},
 'Club': {0: 'Al-Nassr', 1: 'Miami', 2: 'Retired', 3: 'Al Hilal'},
 'Number': {0: 7, 1: 10, 2: None, 3: 10}}

I want to compare new df (based on Name + ID) to old df and return a new df with a column that indicates changes:
      Name       Id      Club       Number  Changes
0     Ronaldo    12414   Al-Nassr   7       No change
1     Messi      4344134 Miami      10      Number
2     Shevchenko 1234435 Retired    None    Club, Number
3     Neymar     423552  Al Hilal   10      New entry

I care mostly for new additions and changes, but if it is not too hard include the removed ones, that would be great. If it changes a lot, then no need. So the results with it will be sth like this:
      Name       Id      Club       Number  Changes
0     Ronaldo    12414   Al-Nassr   7       No change
1     Messi      4344134 Miami      10      Number
2     Shevchenko 1234435 Retired    None    Club, Number
3     Neymar     423552  Al Hilal   10      New entry
4     Maradona   37346   Retired    None    Removed


A generic and vectorial approach to this could be to concat the two DataFrames, then compare them:
# define keys to align the rows
keys = ['Name', 'Id']

# combine the DataFrames after aligning on the keys
tmp = pd.concat({'old': df_old.set_index(keys).assign(flag_=''),
                 'new': df_new.set_index(keys).assign(flag_='')}, axis=1)

# identify new/removed rows
m1 = tmp[('new', 'flag_')].isna()
m2 = tmp[('old', 'flag_')].isna()

# identify changed columns
m = (tmp['old'].ne(tmp['new']) & tmp['old'].notna()).drop(columns='flag_')

# compute output
out = (tmp['new'].fillna(tmp['old']).drop(columns='flag_')
       .join(m.melt(ignore_index=False, var_name='Changes')
              .query('value').groupby(level=keys)['Changes'].agg(', '.join)
              .reindex(tmp.index, fill_value='No change')
              .mask(m1, 'Removed').mask(m2, 'New entry')
            )
       .reset_index()
      )

Output:
         Name       Id      Club  Number       Changes
0     Ronaldo    12414  Al-Nassr     7.0     No change
1       Messi  4344134     Miami    10.0        Number
2  Shevchenko  1234435   Retired     7.0  Club, Number
3    Maradona    37346   Retired     NaN       Removed
4      Neymar   423552  Al Hilal    10.0     New entry

Variant:
# define keys to align the rows
keys = ['Name', 'Id']

# combine the DataFrames after aligning on the keys
tmp = pd.concat({'old': df_old.set_index(keys).assign(Changes='Removed'),
                 'new': df_new.set_index(keys).assign(Changes='New entry')}, axis=1)

# combine columns in order
out = tmp.groupby(level=1, axis=1).first()
# new pandas versions
#out = tmp.T.groupby(level=1).first().T

# identify mismatches
m = (tmp['old'].ne(tmp['new']) & tmp['old'].notna()).drop(columns='Changes')

# update output
s = (m.melt(ignore_index=False, var_name='Changes')
      .query('value').groupby(level=keys)['Changes'].agg(', '.join)
    )
out.loc[s.index, 'Changes'] = s
out = out.reset_index()[df_new.columns.tolist()+['Changes']]

